# Redirect component problem and URL rendering

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect

I'm having trouble with the Redirect component. When the back-btn button is pressed, the closeSesion function is executed, which deletes a data stored on the device and then redirects to the / home url

It is effectively redirected to the home url but the screen remains blank, until the page is manually reloaded with the browser's reload page button. Why? I think when you redirect to / home, it doesn't render

How can I solve it?

```
const Close = () => {

  const [done,setDone]=useState(false)

  const closeSesion = () =>{
     removeItem("isRegistered");

     setDone(true)
  }

  if(done){

    return(<Redirect push={true} to="/home/" />);

  }else{

    
          return (
            <>
            <IonHeader>
              <IonToolbar>
              <div className="header">

                <IonButton  id="back-btn" onClick={() => { closeSesion () } }>CLOSE SESION</IonButton>
              </div>
            </IonContent>
          </>
          );        
    }

 }
```

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isReg, setIsReg] = useState(false);
return(
<IonApp>
<IonReactRouter>
<IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
      <Menu />
  <IonRouterOutlet id="main">

    <Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   <Home />:<Inicio /> } />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true}></Route>

  </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonSplitPane>
</IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>

);
};
```

Comment: It's working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-amkpt5?file=index.js

Comment: Ok, but I don't want the button to redirect me only, but to execute a function and when it ends it redirects me

Comment: Aww ok, can you post the function? is its a async function?

Comment: It is  const closeSesion () that is inside Close

Comment: What are your routes ? Can you add them ? Have you tried withtout the last backslash ? ``to="/home"`` ?

Comment: I added it. They are in App component

Comment: try with ``to="/home"`` without the last backslash ! Your route is ``exact={true}`` so it won't match ``/home/``